# How to derive distribution of correlation coefficients under bivariate normal condition

Tags: statistics, correlation

X and Y are  bivariate normal and r is the correlation coefficients. If X,Y independent.
I want to show : $\frac{r}{\sqrt{(1-r^2)/(n-2)}}$ follows $t_{n-2}$ distribution.

Comment: what is random there?

Comment: x,y are all random vectors

Comment: correlation coefficients are non-random. so how to define a distribution for something deterministic?